# ASP .NET MVC - Multi Level URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

New to ASP MVC 6 (and ASP in general) and was looking for some guidance.

Currently I've got a default route setup in this fashion:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));
        app.UseFileServer();
    }
```

In my application, I'm looking to have a few routes:

`/projects/{id?}` - Returns Index if id is empty/invalid or uses a controller Projects(id)

`/projects/{id?}/phase/{id?}` - Returns Project(id) if phase id is empty/invalid or uses a controller Phase(id).

Any ideas on how I could best set this up?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on routes, but this should work:

```
app.UseMVC(routes => {
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "project",
        url: "project/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, controller="Project", action="Index"});
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "projectphase",
        url: "project/{id}/phase/{pid}",
        defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, pid=UrlParameter.Optional, controller="Phase", action="Index" });
    });
```

For the invalid/empty pid, just use [RedirectToAction()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) to send the user back to the other route.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is that to create a route to accept both Project ID and Phrase ID, then do the condition within any controllers

In your routeConfig.cs, create a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "MyCustomRoute",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{projectID}/{phraseID}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", projectID = UrlParameter.Optional, phraseID= UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then for example, you have a controller named project

```
public ActionResult CheckID(int projectID, int phraseID) {
  ViewBag.projectID= projectID;
  ViewBag.phraseID= phraseID;
  if (...check my projectID is valid...) {
    ... return to your project view ...
  } else {
    ... return to your phrase view ...
  }
}
```

The actual URL would be something like this

```
http://mydomain/Project/CheckID/1/2
```